# View animation while moving on Screen in android?

Tags: android, animation, view

I had 2 views in an activity. One full screen (View1) and other small (View2), half the size of View1.

I can move View2, over View1 by catching onTouch listeners (`ACTION_UP`/`ACTION_DOWN`). But i want to show animation/dragging image of View2 while moving on View1. Any suggestion on how to implement this, will be appreciated.

Currently, for moving the View2 in four corner, i'm setting the Layout params in `ACTION_UP`.

Code::

```
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
     int dx=0,dy=0;


         switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              int x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                  int y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
         dx = (int) motionEvent.getRawX()  - layoutParams.leftMargin;
                      dy = (int)motionEvent.getRawY() - layoutParams.topMargin;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) ((int) motionEvent.getRawX()-dx);
                layoutParams.topMargin = (int) ((int)motionEvent.getRawY()- dy);
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);             
                break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
         }
         return true;
     }
```

Comment: Some code would be aprecated

Comment: what exactly does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ACTION_MOVE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MOVE) and calculate the offset by checking a pointer's `x` or `y` value. After that set weight or height/width parameter of the `floating` View.

Comment: http://blahti.wordpress.com/?s=animation+image+of+one+view+on+other+image check this link maybe you got some help.